# I have a problem in my code when updating react-navigation v2 to v3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to update the react-navigation library V2 to V3 and change part of my code thinking that there would not be any problems but it turns out that I have problems creating createStackNavigator with a screen of type createDrawerNavigator and that in turn contains createBottomTabNavigator.

my code that works with the previous version was:

```
export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  const commonNavigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      shadowColor: 'transparent',
      elevation: 0
    },
    headerTintColor: DEFAULT_THEME.topaz
  };

  const SignedIn = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: Drawer('Home'),
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          headerStyle: {
            height: 0
          },
          header: getSafeArea(DEFAULT_THEME.backgrouncolorHomeSafeArea)
        })
      },
      Cards: {
        screen: Tabs('Cards'),
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          headerStyle: {
            height: 0
          }
        })
      },
   );

const SignedOut = createStackNavigator(
    {
      SignIn: {
        screen: LoginContainer,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          headerStyle: {
            height: 0
          },
          header: getSafeArea(DEFAULT_THEME.dark)
        })
      },
      SelectableCardsList: { screen: SelectableCardsListComponent },
);

  return createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      SignedIn: { screen: SignedIn },
      SignedOut: { screen: SignedOut }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? 'SignedIn' : 'SignedOut'
    }
  );
};


const Drawer = (initialRoute) => createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Tabs('Home') },

  {
    initialRouteName: initialRoute,
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
  }
);

const Tabs = (initialRouteName) => createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeContainer,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: I18n.t('tabs.me')
      }
    },
    Home2: {
      screen: Home2,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: I18n.t('tabs.credentials')
      }
 },
  {
    initialRouteName: initialRouteName,
    tabBarComponent: ({ navigation }) => <CustomBottomBarComponent navigation={navigation} navigationState={navigation['state']} />,
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white'
      }
    }
  }
);
```

try this solution with react-navigation V3 and send me an error

I try the following:
encapsulate createSwitchNavigator in createAppContainer and separate (SignedOut and SignedOut) createStackNavigator out of createSwitchNavigator, the rest is still the same.

```
export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        SignedIn: { screen: SignedIn },
        SignedOut: { screen: SignedOut }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: signedIn ? 'SignedIn' : 'SignedOut'
    }
));
```

I get the following error: The component for route 'Home' must be a react component. For Example

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Home : MyScreen,
}
you can also use a navigator:
The problem is located in this part:

```
const SignedIn = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: Drawer,
```

Also try to change Drawer for any component (a component with a blank screen) and this works, but I can not insert the Tabs in the Drawer.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: jhonly, in the `SignedIn` routing, how did you import `Drawer`? I ask because I am having a similar problem, it seems it may be related to how you are importing your components, unfortunately I have not completely resolved it for mine.